# Can I create AWS Quicksight dashboard programmatically?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-quicksight

I want to create the dashboard dynamically using dynamic MySQL query. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title asks if you can create a QuickSight dashboard programmatically. The answer is no. The only [QuickSight APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) are for managing Users and Groups.

Your question then asks if you can use Dynamic MySQL queries. [Using a SQL Query - Amazon QuickSight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-SQL-query.html) says:

> When creating a new data set based on a direct query to a database, you can choose an existing SQL query or create a new SQL query.

That might be what you seek.